# (SuiteCRM) Event module transformation (logic hook?)

Tags: crm, suitecrm

I don’t know if the place is correct but I would like a help to understand.
I looked for some things here on the forum, however none that involved date and time.
In logic hooks it is complicated to assemble.
In the Events module, I would like to prevent the user from using certain data for a certain period.

**Example:** If between the start date and time and the end date and time and determining the dropdown contains the same date and dropdown data already recorded in the chosen period, avoid recording it with a warning message.

In short: it is like a reservation where the dropdown data during the recorded period and considering the minutes cannot be repeated.

I don’t know if I was clear, but I would just like to transform the event module as a reservation module.

Hugs.

***UPDATE:***

I found a brief solution to what I need. Using logic hooks.
I created this code so that the information if the reservation is available or not after recording (after_save). I did not want to use before_save because I would like this to be registered as an error when the user did not notice.

```
<?php
if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');
require_once 'include/entryPoint.php';

class CheckerEventsLogicHook{
     public function CheckerDates($bean, $event, $arguments){
        global $db; 

$date_start1 = $bean->date_start;
$date_start = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date_start1, new DateTimeZone('UTC'))->format('Y-m-d\H:i:s'); 
$date_end1 = $bean->date_end;
$date_end = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date_end1, new DateTimeZone('UTC'))->format('Y-m-d\H:i:s');   
$sala_c     = $bean->sala_c;

$sql = "SELECT fpc.id_c FROM fp_events fp, fp_events_cstm fpc WHERE fp.deleted = 0 and fpc.id_c = fp.id AND fp.date_start >= '$date_start' AND fp.date_end <= '$date_end' AND fpc.sala_c = '$sala_c' AND fpc.id_c <> '$bean->id' ";

$res = $db->query($sql);

if ($db->getRowCount($res) > 0) {

            $db->query(" UPDATE fp_events_cstm SET reserva_status_c='✖ ERROR!', rejeitadomotivo_c=' Change dates! ' where fp_events_cstm.id_c='$bean->id'");
     
          SugarApplication::appendErrorMessage('<span style="color: red; display: block; width: 100%; font-size: 18px; text-align: center; margin-top: 18px;"> A error occurred!</span>');
                $params = array(
                  'module' => 'FP_events',
                  'action' => 'EditView', 
                 'record' => $bean->id, 
                );
                
      SugarApplication::redirect('index.php?' . http_build_query($params));
                            }
else {

      SugarApplication::appendErrorMessage('<span style="color: green; display: block; width: 100%; font-size: 15px; text-align: center; margin-top: 15px;">Saved Successfully!</span>');

};}}
?>
```

However, it only works if the date is exactly the same as the date in the database.
I based it on the query I made and it worked very well, but the PHP code is not working.

Query working:

```
select fpc.id_c, fp.date_start, fp.date_entered
 from fp_events fp, fp_events_cstm fpc
 WHERE fp.deleted =0
 and fpc.id_c = fp.id
and fp.date_start  >= '2021-02-28\05:00:00'
and fp.date_end <= '2021-02-28\10:00:00'
 and fpc.sala_c = 'AUD_BARATA'
and fpc.id_c <> '9afe8e46-14a4-3abf-0dd4-60300c8c8306'; // ID ignored to Save
```

Where do I find the error in my PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a hard time understanding the requirement but if you need AJAX validation with some rules, you can usually create your own PHP file to respond to those requests.

There is a guide on how to extend SuiteCRM https://docs.suitecrm.com/developer/extension-framework/

Another option is to do javascript validation, updating the module `vardefs.php`, quickly is something like

```
 'validation' => 
array (
  'type' => 'callback',
  'callback' => 'function(formname,nameIndex){if($("#" + nameIndex).val()!=999){add_error_style(formname,nameIndex,"Only 999 is allowed!"); return false;}; return true;}',
),
```

UPDATE:
Regarding Dates, SuiteCRM stores dates as UTC regardless of the user configuration, so you will always have to convert dates to UTC before doing queries.

User settings contain the user timezone, which you can use to translate the date to UTC.  `$current_user` global contains those settings for your convenience.

Comment: I had already used it. But using it with datetime just got really complicated. I updated the post to better understand my thinking.

Comment: I updated the code. Is my PHP query broken?

Comment: But that's exactly what I did on the variable. I want the schedule to be from the database, because users will be at (-03: 00). And the database is in UTC 0. The Form sends the format dd / mm / yyyy  H:i:s.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. The error was in my SELECT.
This SELECT must be concatenated between date_start and date_end for that all schedules are analyzed. Here is the select:

```
select fpc.id_c , fp.date_start, fp.date_end, fp.name
from fp_events fp, fp_events_cstm fpc
WHERE fp.deleted =0
and fpc.id_c = fp.id
and fpc.sala_c = 'AUD_BARATA'
and ((fp.date_start BETWEEN '2021-02-28 13:00' AND '2021-02-28 16:00')
or (fp.date_end between '2021-02-28 13:00' and '2021-02-28 16:00')
or ('2021-02-28 13:00' between fp.date_start and fp.date_end)
or ('2021-02-28 16:00' between fp.date_start and fp.date_end))
and fpc.id_c <> '98880fc3-ef30-1046-0364-60328f45aa2c'; //ID ignored on the search
```

The minutes and seconds are now being considered. If anyone wants to validate the code or improve it, let me know so I can complete this question.